# the usage of this in the class definition

Tags: java

With respect to the following class definition:

```
public final class ConfigComparer {
    ...some code ....

    public ConfigComparer(String defaultFile, String siteFile)
       throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
       this.defaultFile = defaultFile;
       this.siteFile = siteFile;
       defaultConfig = loadConfiguration(defaultFile);
       siteConfig = loadConfiguration(siteFile);
       load();
    }
    ..... some code  ....

}
```

Inside the constructor `ConfigComparer`, there are `this.defaultFile = defaultFile;` and `this.siteFile = siteFile;`  what are these two `this.` used for or what are their design considerations?

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the instance/object that your code is running inside.

`this.defaultFile` references the instance variable `defaultFile` of the class `ConfigComparer`.

`defaultFile` references the variable passed into the constructor.

**When `this` is not specified, it always looks for local variables, before instance variables.**

Answer (score 0):

Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a `constructor` by using `this`.

From within a constructor, `this` keyword to call another `constructor` in the same class. Doing so is called an explicit constructor invocation.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

The class definition should be something like this:

```
public final class ConfigComparer {

    private String defaultFile;

    private String siteFile;

    ...some code ....
}
```

And, in the constructor, you are assigning the parameters `(String  defaultFile, String  siteFile)` to those attributes. Note that if the attributes would have a different name this is not required, but in this case it it, if not then you are assigning to the parameters their same value.

Comment: I personally always use `this` regardless of whether it's a name conflict or not. It's much more readable, and saves you the time of checking if there's a local variable with that name.

Comment: Me too. It also makes it easier to change/debug code with syntax highlight.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), `this` refers to `Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object`

Your code constructor can be written without `this` keyword
like

```
public ConfigComparer(String defaultFile, String siteFile)
   throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
   instance_defaultFile = defaultFile;
   instance_siteFile = siteFile;
   defaultConfig = loadConfiguration(defaultFile);
   siteConfig = loadConfiguration(siteFile);
   load();
}
```

In your constructor, the keyword `this` is necessary since both your `instance variable` and your `method parameter` are the same, the jvm needs to know what you are referring to and thats why you need to say

`this.defaultFile = defaultFile`